# Having an issue with displaying most recent Call_date

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to output the most recent Call_date. I have tried using the MAX function with no luck. Below I have tagged 3 images showing the database tables, my current code output and the required output. Underneath that is my current code. Any help is appreciated!

Database Tables - https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNtGB.jpg

Output we are looking for - https://i.stack.imgur.com/nY7fv.jpg

Output my code currently gives - https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnHvs.jpg

Here is what I have tried:

```
SELECT Staff.First_name, Staff.Last_name, call_date, taken_by
FROM  Issue
JOIN Caller ON Issue.Caller_id = Caller.Caller_id
JOIN Staff ON Issue.Taken_by = Staff.Staff_code 
WHERE Caller.First_name = 'Harry'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just add the following to the end of your query:

```
ORDER BY call_date DESC LIMIT 1
```

This will give you one row as a result. And that row will be the one with the most recent call_date.

Comment: Thanks Billy! Exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: No problem @JoeBloggs! Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code provided, you're only asking for 3 columns so it's a matter of a join.  When you select the max call date you need to group by the other 2 non-aggregate columns. If the date column is of datatype Date or Datetime then this should work:

```
SELECT Caller.First_name, Caller.Last_name --from Caller_id       
      ,MAX(Issue.call_date) AS call_date

  FROM  Issue INNER JOIN Caller ON Issue.Caller_id = Caller.Caller_id                     

 WHERE Caller.First_name = 'Harry'

GROUP BY Caller.First_name, Caller.Last_name
```